# jQuery portlets, textfields are not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a set of jQuery portlets with some textfields in them. But i can't edit the textfields. This only seem to be happening in FireFox (12.0).

An example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xXwP7/

Anyone any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: @Raminson Nice, that indeed fixed the problem :) Can you add this as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line `$( ".column" ).disableSelection();` make them disabled.